# compare data between two tables and populate a flag column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, compare

i have TABLEA and TABLEB

```
Table A:
Create table TableA (ID INT, A1 DECIMAL(6,5), A2 DECIMAL(6,5), A3 DECIMAL(6,5), A4 DECIMAL(10,9), FLAGB1 CHAR(1), FLAGB2 CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO TABLEA (ID, A1, A2, A3, A4)
VALUES(1, 1.1111, 2.2222, 3.3333, 4.4444 ), (2, 1.2345, 2.2345, 3.2345, 4.2345),(3, 1.2222, 2.2222, 3.2222, 4.2222)
TABLE B:
CREATE TABLE TABLEB (ID INT, B1 DECIMAL(6,5), B2 DECIMAL(6,5))
INSERT INTO TABLEB (ID, B1, B2)
VALUES (1, 1.1111, 1.2345), (2, 2.2222, 3.3333), (3, 5.2222,3.2222)
```

I would like to compare `B1` with `A1, A2, A3, A4` and if there is any matching number then put 'Y' on `FLAGB1` else put 'N'.

Likewise, compare `B2` with `A1, A2, A3, A4` and if there is any matching number then put 'Y' on `FLAGB2` else put an 'N' on `TABLEA`.

Note: Actual tables have thousands of rows and about 60 columns.

```
OUTPUT:
TABLEA:
ID----A1-----------A2-----------A3----------A4-----FLAGB1----FLAGB2
1---1.11110-----2.22220------3.33330------4.44440-----Y---------N
2---1.23450-----2.23450------3.23450------4.23450-----N---------N
3---1.22220-----2.22220------3.22220------4.22220-----N---------Y
```

So far I have tried:

```
    DECLARE @NUM1 decimal(6,5), @NUM2 decimal(6,5)
    DECLARE @END INT, @COUNT INT
    SET @COUNT= 1
    SELECT @END =MAX(ID) FROM TABLEB

    WHILE @COUNT <= @END
    BEGIN
        SELECT @NUM1= B1  FROM TABLEB WHERE ID = @COUNT         
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLEA WHERE @NUM1 IN (A1,A2,A3,A4) AND ID =@count)

            UPDATE TABLEA               
              SET FLAGB1 = 'Y'
            where ID = @count
                            ELSE
                                 UPDATE TABLEA
                                 SET FLAGB1='N'
                                 WHERE ID=@COUNT
             SELECT @NUM2= B2  FROM TABLEB WHERE ID = @COUNT            
      IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLEA WHERE @NUM2 IN (A1,A2,A3,A4) AND ID =@count)

            UPDATE TABLEA               
                SET FLAGB2 = 'Y'
            where ID = @count
                            ELSE
                                 UPDATE TABLEA
                             SET FLAGB2='N'
                                 WHERE ID=@COUNT
             SET @COUNT-@COUNT+1
    END

                   SELECT * FROM TABLEA
```

I get random 'Y' and 'N' on Flag columns which does not satisfy the logic. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems straight forward to me as long as you don't introduce loops.

```
UPDATE a
SET FLAGB1 = CASE WHEN EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM TABLEB WHERE b.B1 in (a.A1, a.A2, a.A3, a.A4)) 
   THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'  END,
    FLAGB2 = CASE WHEN EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1 FROM TABLEB WHERE b.B2 in (a.A1, a.A2, a.A3, a.A4)) 
   THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'  END
FROM TABLEA a
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. columns A1,A2,A3,A4 are in tableA. and columns B1 and B2 are in tableB.. you seemed to understand the opposite. can you please explain may be i am not getting it. BTW i fixed my query and it works now `SELECT 1 FROM TABLEA WHERE @NUM2 IN (A1,A2,A3,A4) AND ID =@count)` edited as `SELECT 1 FROM TABLEA A WHERE @NUM2 IN (A.A1,A.A2,A.A3,A.A4) AND ID =@count)

Comment: sqlsean I tried again. I hope i got it right this time